# Use existing html page elements (its form and button) withing django app

Tags: python, django, forms, textarea

My goal is to run python function when a user clicks on a button within a form on my web page, when the argument is taken from **textarea** HTML element.
The following html code is my form with button within and is part of **django** application.

```
<div id="contact_form" class="col_400 float_l">
      <form id="demoForm"  name="contact" >  

         <label for="text">Your Review:</label>
         <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
         <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

         <input type="button" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="predictSentBtn" value="Predict" />

      </form>
</div>
```

I looked on **django.forms and django.forms.widgets**, but still don't understand how to "link" between existing html elements and python objects.

Comment: You have no way to use a server-side python function as the client-side `onclick` event handler.

Comment: Not 100% clear but it sounds like you need to be checking for `if request.method == 'POST':` in your view and then check for the values of `request.POST` for whatever you want to take back from the form

Comment: @jaux. Sorry, you're right. It's local site now, so it should work locally .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
<div id="contact_form" class="col_400 float_l">
  <form id="demoForm"  name="contact" >  

     <label for="text">Your Review:</label>
     <textarea id="needid" name="needid" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
     <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>

     <input type="button" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="predictSentBtn" value="Predict" />

  </form>
```

```
 def function(request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        print request.POST['needid'] # print request.POST.get('needid')
```

Try it ;)

Comment: POST is a dictionary - Fix the syntax

Comment: @Silwestpl Thank you. It helps to extract content of the textarea. Maybe, you know how to make it happen, when one clicks the button?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question... can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Silwestpl I mean, how to cause the view function be called when I click the button inside the form?

Comment: :)`<form id="demoForm"  name="contact" action="{% url app.views.function %}">` there you go :)